# Como puedo añadir a método .add de ActionErrors de struts una cadena de texto sin que sea pasada por un archivo.properties?

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts

Estoy trabajando con html, javascript, struts1, oracle11, jQuery, spring, tiles, etc... Y tengo el siguiente problema.

Intentando homogeneizar todos los mensajes de error, me he encontrado con una solución que me ayudaría mucho, me ahorraría trabajo y código a la vez. El caso es que en algunas de mis ventanas voy a mostrar el mensaje de la siguiente forma:

```
    if (resul==null ){
        errors.add("Generico",new ActionError("error.mntr.nullpointer"));
    }
```

Esto me muestra de forma correcta el mensaje tal y como yo quiero, pero el caso es que en algunas otras ventanas no puedo realizarlo de la siguiente forma por el simple hecho de que tengo que identificar el error y notificar en la ventana lo que sale por consola, y esto no lo puedo añadir siempre a un properties, por lo que intenté hacer lo siguiente:

```
     } catch (Exception adex) {
        logger.error(
            "error en T002Action: "+adex.toString(), adex);
        errors.add("Generico",new ActionError("error en T002Action: "+adex.toString()));
        forward = mapping.findForward("error");
    }
```

Lógicamente esto hace que struts me lance un aviso con el siguiente mensaje: "***[ServletException in:clase.jsp] Cannot find bean Generico in any scope.*** Entiendo porque me da el error y ayer ya desistí en buscar más, pero mi pregunta por curiosidad y último esfuerzo en intentarlo hacer de esta forma es: ¿Existe alguna forma de pasarle al método .add dicha cadena de texto?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si la versión de Struts que estás utilizando lo soporta, puedes agregar un mensaje de *error* de la siguiente manera:

```
errors.add("Generico",new ActionMessage("error en T002Action: "+adex.toString(), false));
```

Con `false`, le indicas al *framework* que se trata de un mensaje literal y que no debe ser tomado de un *bundle* (*properties*).

Comment: Gracias @Paul he añadido eso y no me da ningún tipo de error, pero me sigue apareciendo por pantalla **Cannot find bean Generico in any scope** he depurado y veo que, cuando antes solo me salía la cadena como **key** y valor=null en `errors`. Ahora me sale el valor como object y dentro contiene un boolean. Imagino que como dices será por la versión. No se si cambiar a la 1.3, crees que funcionaría?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar a utilizar los parámetros del `ActionError` para pasarle un `String`:

```
errors.add("Generico", new ActionMessage("error.custom", message));
```

y en el properties:

```
error.custom = {0}
```

Puedes ver la posibles sobrecargas del método en la [documentación](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/archive/trunk/struts-doc-1.1/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionError.html).